# My navigation menu works fine in FF and Chrome, but in older version of IE it's terrible plain looking text

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, nav

[Here is what I've done.](http://foxklld.site88.net/test/nav/nav.html)
How to make navigation menu similar to FF and Chrome in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, there is not support for radial gradients in all browsers, but if you are willing to settle for top to bottom gradient, there you go:

```
/* SVG fallback(Opera 11.10-, IE9) */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxkZWZzPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZ3JhZGllbnQiIHgxPSIwJSIgeTE9IjAlIiB4Mj0iMTAwJSIgeTI9IjAlIj48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjAlIiBzdHlsZT0ic3RvcC1jb2xvcjpyZ2JhKDg1LDg1LDg1LDEpOyIgLz48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0eWxlPSJzdG9wLWNvbG9yOnJnYmEoNTEsNTEsNTEsMSk7IiAvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZGllbnQpIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiAvPjwvc3ZnPg==);

/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(85,85,85,1), rgba(51,51,51,1));

/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(85,85,85,1), rgba(51,51,51,1));

/* Chrome 7+ & Safari 5.03+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, rgba(85,85,85,1)), color-stop(1, rgba(51,51,51,1)));

/* IE5.5 - IE7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1,StartColorStr=#FF555555,EndColorStr=#FF333333);

/* IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1,StartColorStr=#FF555555,EndColorStr=#FF333333)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE do not know the following css you are using:

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom, #555, #333);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(bottom, #555, #333);
-webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
```

If someone can answer this question with an alternative for CSS3 and older browser versions, i'll be very intrested. But untill then, i guess you'll have to wait until all common browsers support CSS3.